# Where did Data.Functor.Coproduct. go?

Tags: haskell, package

I'm trying to use `Data.Functor.Coproduct` from [`comonad`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/comonad-4.0/docs/Data-Functor-Coproduct.html), but it seem to have disappeared in the latest version.

In the [changelog](https://github.com/ekmett/comonad/blob/master/CHANGELOG.markdown) it is mentioned that it was deprecated in favor of [`Data.Functor.Sum`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Sum.html), but I don't know where I can find an equivalent `coproduct` function for `Sum`:

```
coproduct :: (f a -> b) -> (g a -> b) -> Coproduct f g a -> b
```

Comment: Well, `coproduct f g = \case {InL fa -> f fa; InR ga -> g ga}`.

Comment: Indeed, but it would be nice not to have to reinvent this every time ;)

Comment: Depending on your use case, you might be able to use `foldMap` to extract the desired value.

Comment: I think that really should be added to `Data.Functor.Sum` by some name. Nothing shows up in Hayoo.